# Getting Swift 4.2 to load Core Data Store from previous Objective-C build

Tags: ios, swift, core-data-migration

So I've got an older ObjC Core Data App that I'm rewriting from the ground up in Swift 4.2 but I can't get the PersistentContainer of Swift to locate the NSManagedObjectModel from ObjC. The App is already in the AppStore so I obviously need my new Swift version to load the current store that's already on the user's device.

When I print out the directory of the original ObjC Model it shows me:

```
/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2DB3B49C-E397-427E-A30C-273C2738B253/data/Containers/Data/Application/7B1BCD4F-91F8-45AD-9634-4F1D71205EEB/Documents/Model.sqlite
```

... but when I do the same in my Swift rewrite it shows me:

```
/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2DB3B49C-E397-427E-A30C-273C2738B253/data/Containers/Data/Application/AB13D4B1-01E2-477D-B6D1-295F4AD0F1BB/Documents/Model.sqlite
```

The last string of numbers right before the 'Documents' directory are very different.

Since the Store isn't in the same directory my Swift rewrite just creates an entirely new store and goes from there. Interestingly enough, if I load my old ObjC version "back over" the Swift rewrite in the simulator it still loads the original store back up - so there's clearly 2 completely different stores in two different directories.

How do I get my current Swift rewrite to load up the old store? Swift 4.2 is now using PersistentContainer and I thought I'd be able to grab the original store using the following:

```
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
```

... but it still doesn't work. I'm still unable to locate and migrate the old store. I can't believe I'm the only person that's experienced this but for the life of me can't find any stackoverflow suggestions that work. Thoughts anyone?

I've tried

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")

        let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let url = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            print("loading stores")
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        return container
    }()
```

But it's still not loading the old store Model.

Comment: Is that code above executed, did you step through it? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Well, it looks like your application is a different application. Did you change the bundle identifier?

Comment: Mike - Bundle identifier is the same. The Swift version will overwrite the ObjC version in the simulator but load a different store. I can then reload the ObjC version over the Swift version in the simulator and it shows the old store - so there's 2 stores in there somehow - but the App exists only once in the simulator.

Comment: Koen - Stepped through the lazy var persistentContainer without any errors. went all the way through to container.loadPersistentStores, output "loading stores" and returned the container. It's just the wrong container. It's a new one, not the preexisting one.

Comment: If you run ObjC or Swift app, is it always linked to the same path?

Comment: Sachin - That's the issue that I'm having. I can't seem to locate the right path to the original store. I thought I had it with

let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

but that's doesn't get me there.

Answer (score 0):

For those with similar update issues, a lot of trial and error seems to have provided the answer. Here's how I located the old store within Swifts new persistentContainer:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let filePath = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: filePath)
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

Thanks all those out there.